# how to record multiple mouse clicks in c#

Tags: c#, image, list, graphics, draw

I am trying to create a paint program in c#, I have got the Objects to draw on the screen when I click the mouse. Know what I am trying to do is record all the places that the user clicks so that I can redraw the graphics later. I know I could do it with a list with this:

```
Point recordpoint = new Point(i.X, i.Y);
List<Point> pts = new List<Point>();
pts.Add(recordpoint);
```

This only adds the last mouse click and I need to know how add an infinite amount of mouse clicks to the list and I have no idea how to do this.

I would love it if anyone new how to do this.

Comment: What event are you doing this on? Where is `i` coming from?

Comment: Show us more of your code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new list every time you add a point.

Move `List<Point> pts` into the top level of your Form class, so you are creating one list only.

```
class PaintForm : Form {

    // declare a list of points as a field
    private List<Point> pts = new List<Point>();

    // ..

    private void PictureBox1_OnMouseDown(..) {  // or whereever this code was
        Point recordpoint = new Point(i.X, i.Y);
        pts.Add(recordpoint);    
    }

    // ..
}
```

Comment: Okay, so how do I get the items in the list and draw objects in the location where I clicked.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to write your program for you, but you said you already know how to draw an object where the user clicked, and you can use a `foreach` loop to go through every point that you saved in your `pts` list: `foreach (var pt in pts) { /* draw object at pt */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an "OnClick" event available to handle then you can just move the collection to the class level and item new items on click:

```
public class MyClass
{

List<Point> pts = new List<Point>();//This way the member persists

public void OnClick(TypeName i, EventArgs e)//whatever params are..
{
    Point recordpoint = new Point(i.X, i.Y);//create element
    pts.Add(recordpoint);//insert into collection
}

}
```